# Top navigation menu stopped displaying

Tags: category, menu, navigation

I am developing magento application using the enterprise edition. Everything was working fine until I gave an option 'Use Flat Catalog Category': 'Yes'. Now the top navigation displays only one category without any child categories in it. I this setting is changed to 'No', it works fine. Any one knows what is causing this problem or how to solve this. The categories are created under 'Default Category'. It seems the project is working great in my localhost but in server only on category is shown and its child categories are not shown. Any one please help. will be greatfull.

Comment: Try rebuilding the flat category index.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try rebuilding the category index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, it seams that the problem was solved by rebuilding the indexes.

Comment: Yes the problem is solved, Thanks @Marius